# Drag and zoom text with Kineticjs

Tags: text, kineticjs, zooming

I am trying to zoom and pan a text which is draggable already. All the examples are on images or shapes and it seems I cannot adapt it to a text object. My questions are:

1. Do I have to use the anchors or is any simpler way zoom a text with Kineticjs?
2. I found an example regarding zooming a shape and the code crashes here:

   ```
     var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        drawFunc : drawTriangle  //drawTriangle is a function defined already
     });
   ```

Can we call a function while we are creating a layer?
I usually create a layer and then add the outcome of the function in it.
Any idea would be great, thanks.

Comment: I assume you were going off of this tutorial: http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/07/scalable-draggable-anchored-triangle-in.html in which he is using KineticJS 3.10.0 which is extremely outdated. Could you describe in more detail what you mean about zoom and pan a text? Do you want the text size to increase/decrease? Or actually zoom in with scale? How do you want to pan the text besides dragging it?

Comment: Thanks projeqht for your advice.
I under estimated the KineticsJS version he was using. I want to do this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/  but with a text object instead of an image, thus no loadImages function. I can drag and drop it but not zoom it like in the example.
Cannot seem to make it work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of many ways you could do this but this is the one I ended up implementing: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/42C2t/)

Basically, you have an anchor (which doesn't always have to be there, you can hide and show it if you would like. Let me know if you need help with that) and if you drag the anchor down it increases the `fontSize`, and if you drag the anchor up it decreases the `fontSize`.

I followed the exact same [anchor tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) but instead I added a `dragBoundFunc` to limit dragging to the Y-axis:

```
var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    stroke: '#666',
    fill: '#ddd',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 8,
    name: name,
    draggable: true,
    dragOnTop: false,
    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
        return {
            x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y: pos.y
        };
    }
});
```

And then I updated the `updateAnchor()` function to only detect the single anchor I added to the group named `sizeAnchor`:

```
var mY = 0;

function update(activeAnchor, event) {
  var group = activeAnchor.getParent();
  var sizeAnchor = group.get('.sizeAnchor')[0];
  var text = group.get('.text')[0];

  if (event.pageY < mY) {
    text.setFontSize(text.getFontSize()-1);
  } else {
    text.setFontSize(text.getFontSize()+1);
  }

  sizeAnchor.setPosition(-10, 0);

  mY = event.pageY;
}
```

Basically `mY` is used compared to the `e.PageY` to see if the mouse is moving up or down. Once we can determine the mouse direction, then we can decide if we should increase or decrease the `fontSize`!

Alternatively, you can use the mousewheel to do the exact same thing! I didn't implement it myself but it's definitely doable. Something like:

1. Mousewheel down and the `fontSize` decreases
2. Mousewheel up and the `fontSize` increases

Hopefully this emulates "Zooming" a text for you. And I guess being able to drag the text acts as "panning" right?

**UPDATE (based on comment below)**

This is how you would limit dragging to the Y-Axis using `dragBoundFunc`:

```
var textGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
        return {
            x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y: pos.y
        };
    }
});
```

See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/42C2t/) (same jsfiddle as above)

Comment: Tried your jsfiddle. It's exactly what I needed. Will try to adapt it to my code today and also to hide the anchor unless you click the text. Will keep you updated. Thanks a lot as I have postponed this task for a week by now.

Comment: Hey me again. I managed to adapt your code to mine and it works fine. The only thing is that I need to drag the text totally in vertical(y) as if I try to move it a tiny bit on the x, it will disappear. Thus, I cannot use it still because of course I cannot limit users to drag the text strictly vertically. Any suggestion?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that's what you're looking for! Good luck!

Comment: Still no luck. When I click and try to drag on first text I write(inserted as input), it will zoom it automatically so much it goes out of the canvas and disappears. All this within 1 sec, thus I cannot even have time to drug it properly.

Comment: Managed to work it out. I changed the text.getFontSize() to +3 & -3 instead of -1 & +1. Thanks a lot, finally I got it out of the way.

Comment: Can you help me to make the anchors invisible please as when I save the image on another window, that's not nice to see the anchors there too. Thanks

Comment: See this question for info on selecting and deselecting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550176/kinetic-js-how-do-you-hide-all-the-anchors-for-a-given-group-id

Comment: I have been checking that example since yesterday. Looks good but seems quite different from the way I have approached it so far (the way you suggested me) so it means I will have to change quite a lot of code and it might be a problem. Thnx anyway.

Comment: It should be similar, only that you have 1 anchor instead of the 4. If you're still having more issues maybe create a new question with new details and code/jsfiddle.