# kineticjs show image anchors on click

Tags: html, image, anchor, kineticjs

I have a kineticjs canvas with image upload and text input, both functions are working fine but I can't get the image resize anchors to show... I need to get the image resize anchors to show "onClick" of the image.

any help is much appreciated :)
thanks in advance.

here is the js

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 375,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

//image loader
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            layer.add(new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 100,
                y: 50,
                image: img,
                width: 200,
                height: 130,
                draggable: true
            }));
            text.moveToTop();
            stage.draw();
        };
        console.log(event);
        img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}

// parameters
var resizerRadius = 3;
var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;

// constant
var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

function draw(img, withAnchors, withBorders) {
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // draw the image
    var view = img.view;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, view.left, view.top, view.width, view.height);

    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
    if (withAnchors) {
        drawDragAnchor(view.left, view.top);
        drawDragAnchor(view.left + view.width, view.top);
        drawDragAnchor(view.left + view.width, view.top + view.height);
        drawDragAnchor(view.left, view.top + view.height);
    }

    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
    if (withBorders) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(view.left, view.top, view.width, view.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawText();
}

function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawText(){
    var x = 40,
        y = 100;
    ctx.font = "bold 20px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText($("#textBox").val(), x, y);
}

// -------------------------------------------
//        -        Hit Testing        -
// -------------------------------------------

// return 0,1,2, or 3 if (x,y) hits the respective anchor
//   of the given view.
// return -1 if no anchor hit.
function anchorHitTest(view, x, y) {
    var dx, dy;
    x -= view.left;
    y -= view.top;
    // top-left
    dx = x;
    dy = y;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) return (0);
    // top-right
    dx = x - view.width;
    dy = y;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) return (1);
    // bottom-right
    dx = x - view.width;
    dy = y - view.height;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) return (2);
    // bottom-left
    dx = x;
    dy = y - view.height;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) return (3);
    return (-1);
}

// return true if (x,y) lies within the view
function hitImage(view, x, y) {
    x -= view.left;
    y -= view.top;
    return (x > 0 && x < view.width && y > 0 && y < view.height);
}

// -------------------------------------------
//        -        Mouse        -
// -------------------------------------------

var mousePos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var draggingImage = false;
var startX, startY;
var isDown = false;

var currentImg = null;

var draggingResizer;

function updateMousePos(e) {
    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    updateMousePos = function (e) {
        mousePos.x = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mousePos.y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    };
    return updateMousePos(e);
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    updateMousePos(e);
    // here you could make a loop to see which image / anchor was clicked
    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(img.view, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(img.view, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    // 
    if (draggingResizer<0 && !draggingImage) return;
    startX = mousePos.x;
    startY = mousePos.y;
    currentImg = img;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    if (!currentImg) return;
    draggingResizer = -1;
    draggingImage = false;
    draw(currentImg, true, false);
    currentImg = null;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!currentImg) return;
    updateMousePos(e);

    var view = currentImg.view;
    if (draggingResizer > -1) {
        var oldView = {
            left: view.left,
            top: view.top,
            width: view.width,
            height: view.height
        };
        // resize the image
        switch (draggingResizer) {
            case 0:
                cl('ttoo');
                //top-left
                view.left = mousePos.x;
                view.top = mousePos.y;
                view.width = oldView.left + oldView.width - mousePos.x;
                view.height = oldView.top + oldView.height - mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 1:
                //top-right
                // view.left  unchanged             
                view.top = mousePos.y;
                view.width = mousePos.x - oldView.left;
                view.height = oldView.top + oldView.height - mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 2:
                //bottom-right
                view.width = mousePos.x - oldView.left;
                view.height = mousePos.y - oldView.top;
                break;
            case 3:
                //bottom-left
                view.left = mousePos.x;
                view.width = oldView.left + oldView.width - mousePos.x;
                view.height = mousePos.y - (oldView.top);
                break;
        }

        if (view.width < 25) view.width = 25;
        if (view.height < 25) view.height = 25;

        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
        draw(currentImg, true, true);

    } else if (draggingImage) {
        imageClick = false;

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mousePos.x - startX;
        var dy = mousePos.y - startY;
        view.left += dx;
        view.top += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mousePos.x;
        startY = mousePos.y;

        // redraw the image with border
        draw(currentImg, false, true);
    }
}



var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 20,
    y: 30,
    text: '',
    fontSize: '30',
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: 'black',
    draggable: true
});

stage.add(layer);
layer.add(text);

document.getElementById("textBox").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    text.setText(this.value);
    layer.draw();
}, true);

document.getElementById("textSize").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var size = this.value;
    text.fontSize(size);
    layer.draw();
}, true);

document.getElementById("fontFamily").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var font = this.value;
    text.fontFamily(font);
    layer.draw();
}, true);

document.getElementById("fontStyle").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var style = this.value;
    text.fontStyle(style);
    layer.draw();
}, true);

document.getElementById("fill").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var colour = this.value;
    text.fill(colour);
    layer.draw();
}, true);



$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});

// utility
function cl() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

can provide jsFiddle if needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix KineticJS with html canvas drawing commands.

That combination doesn't work because KineticJS does its magic by taking over the canvas--leaving no ability to call native canvas commands like `context.beginPath`.

```
// these 2 don't play together

... new Kinetic.Image ...

... ctx.beginPath ...
```

Anyway, Here's the answer to your question (in case you choose KineticJS for your project)

Kinetic.Image can be asked to execute a function when the image is clicked like this:

```
var image=new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    image: img,
    width: 200,
    height: 130,
    draggable: true
}));
image.on("click",function(){

    // The image was clicked
    // Show your anchors now

});
layer.add(image);
```

**[ Addition: Example of Kinetic.Image resizing ]**

I don't like the overhead and complexity of maintaining anchors to resize Kinetic.Images.

Here's an example that lets you drag on the right side of the image to scale it proportionally:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/p8bpC/

You could modify this code to add cosmetic resizing grabbers (the grabbers are not necessary, but if you prefer the "anchor" look, you can add them).

Comment: i started building a canvas and switched to kinetic, so how do i turn my jquery anchor commands to kinetic language?

Comment: Personally, I don't like the overhead and complexity that comes with separate resizing anchors.  Instead, I allow resizing like operating systems do--just "grab" one side of a window and drag to resize the window.  I've added an example of this to my answer.  If you prefer the look of "anchors" you can add anchors to the code (the anchors would be functional but purely cosmetic--the resizing is done by dragging the right side).  Good luck with your project!

Comment: yep that's a much cleaner approach!.. thanks for your help :D

Comment: i updated the image with "draggable:true" and its acting weird.. :/

Comment: Well, remember that a "drag" involves the same mouse events as a "resize".  Therefore, when the user does mousedown inside the "resize" area you are *both dragging and resizing--yes, with weird results!*.  So you must disable the "drag" when the user mousedowns inside the "resize" area.  You can disable dragging with myImage.stopDrag().

Comment: would i need an "if" resize area myImage.stopDrag() ??

Comment: Yes, but the "if" is already in the mousedown handler.  Just add stopDrag there: `if (mouseX > right - 25 && mouseX < right + 25) `

Comment: got that working on your fiddle, could you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/pDW34/26/ and see why its not working for me.. massive thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: I have tried to implement this into my fiddle jsfiddle.net/pDW34/33 but its broken the code somewhere, @markE could you see where ive gone wrong??

Comment: I'll take another look :)

Comment: Will do!  (Right now my "day job" is keeping my very busy).

Comment: me too, this has halted the build (am also working on adding it to a facebook tab, no luck yet). but in your own time, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this question, the answers are guided and constructive, and contain a jsfiddle with the exact same behavior that you need.
[Kinetic JS - how do you hide all the anchors for a given group ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550176/kinetic-js-how-do-you-hide-all-the-anchors-for-a-given-group-id)

Comment: appreciate you trying to help but that doesn't help me get my code working, just another maze of code to try and decipher. Im not hot on kinetic and just need some help to get my current code working... please help :/

Comment: I think you're mixing kineticjs and jquery. If you make a jsfiddle we can see things clearer.

Comment: here is a Fiddle jsfiddle.net/pDW34/23 if you could give an easy explanation on how and where to put the example fiddle you linked to. Im not hot on kineticjs but trying lol..